# What does this exam paper C# code do?

Tags: c#

I managed to figure out the code for question 4, but it looks wrong:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string msg = "";
        int i = 1;

        while (i < 6)
        {
            int col = 0;
            while (col < i)
            {
                msg += i;
                col++;
            }
            msg += "\n";
            i++;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
```

Is there a simpler way to do it by using for and if statements?

[image: Home Picture]

Also for question 5, I am completely lost.

Comment: less reddit, more book reading. Tell Muffie I say hi.

Comment: You need to explain what doesnt work, what you have tried, and what it should do

Comment: This is two questions, and so is too broad. I would normally remove the reference to question 5 from in an edit, since it has not been attempted, but several people have answered that below, so I will let it stand. Whilst it is good you've tried question 4, it is not clear what "looks wrong" means. Does it work? Have you tested it?

Answer (score 0):

To solve question four you can use the solution from Enigmativity. For question five I would recommend you something like this:

```
string output = string.Empty;
const string symbol = "*";

//Loop up to the half to print the upcomming way
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{ 
    //Based on index i we need to print asterix
    for (int up = 0; up < i; up++)
    {
      output += symbol;
    }

    //After all asterix are written to string we need a NewLine.
    output += Environment.NewLine;
 }

 //Here we start the same part as above but reverse it
 //So counting from upper end down
 for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--)
 {
    for (int down = 0; down < i; down++)
    {
      output += symbol;
    }

    output += Environment.NewLine;
  }

  //The Trim(); will cut any free spaces before and after the string
  //So we can easily cut the last NewLine which is inserted but not needed
  MessageBox.Show(output.Trim());
```

I hope the code comments explain you what we are doing here. I think it's the easiest way in focus of intelligibility. Both outer for-loops just do the same. First count up to half and second count down from half to end.

Comment: string output = string.Empty;
            const string symbol = "*";
I haven't seen the .empty before nor the const, can you explain what they are and what they do?

Comment: @Michael string output = string.Empty is just a writing for string output = "". Is just a small beauty feature of C# to add more readability. The const Keyword tells the compiler that this value is constant and never can change. Try it yourself and call symbol = "test"; or sth. in your code after the const line. You will become a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

For question no. 5
If you have understand the above answer, i am sure you will come to understand this one also. What i am doing is just printing * instead of numbers i.e **i**, and then a reverse loop.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string msg = "";
   for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++)
   {
     for (var col = 0; col < i; col++)
     {
       msg += "*";
     }
     msg += "\n";
   }
   for (var i = 5; i >= 1; i--)
     {
        for (var col = 0; col< i; col++)
        {
          msg += "*";
        }
        msg += "\n";
     }
   MessageBox.Show(msg.Trim());
}
```

Comment: That one makes a bit more sense -- it's closer to what we've been doing in class, thanks dude!

Comment: @Gaurav Singh This will have a blank line at the end. Use Trim(); to delete the last "\n". In Messagebox you can't see this but if you transfer to console or sth. it's a bit ugly ;-)

Answer (score 0):

for Question 4 you can try this simple code

```
                for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(i);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
```

for Question 5 You Can Use Below Code This Definately works

```
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {       
                for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
                {
                    if (i >= j && i <= 5)
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                    else if (i > 5 && (i+j) <= 11)
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }

                }
                   Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string msg = "";
    for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (var col = 0; col < i; col++)
        {
            msg += i;
        }
        msg += "\n";
    }
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be down-voted - especially so quickly. The OP clearly said it was homework.

Comment: "Try this" is a terrible answer regardless of it being homework since it doesnt explain how it solves the problem

Comment: @Enigmativity Awesome thanks! I just replace the i++) in the second statement with col++ and it worked! +1

Comment: @Michael It might have worked. But did you understand why?

Comment: @Mayank yeah, I understood it, but in class we used for and if statements for questions like that rather than while. Still got no Idea how to do question 5 though I'm still trying haha been at it for an hour

Comment: @Sayse - In this particular case the code is rather simple and the OP asked specifically for code using `for` and `if` statements. There was no need for `if`, so it was super simple and I figured that this was self explanatory.